# How to calculate number or reads operations per second my program does in java?

Tags: java

I need to write a program that writes a block of `100 Byte` length with every `write`.
Every 1000 blocks written, status message should appear as well.

I think I did that successfully, but my issue is with the calculation of number of read operations per second.
I need to calculate how many of them my program does.
I am allowed to use `System.nanoTime()`

Here is what I wrote so far:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class EAWrite {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        int recordsWritten = 0;

        File myFile = new File("D:\\filename.txt");
        FileOutputStream myInputFile = new FileOutputStream(myFile);

        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
            myInputFile.write(100);
            recordsWritten++;

            if ((i % 100) == 0) {
                System.out.println((recordsWritten - 1) + "records written.");
            }
        }
        myInputFile.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: But you haven't tried to calculate and write read operations per second, are you expecting us to write the code for you?

Comment: No, that's not what I am expecting nor want. I don't know where to start. I am unsure whether myInputFile.write(100) counts as a write operation at all.

Comment: Then what are you asking, what is the issue with your code?

Comment: You need to specify the sample rate for your value "read operations per second". Do you want "average read ops per second over all 1000 blocks", or "average read ops per second over the last second" or "average read ops over the entire time your program runs"? From there, somebody might be able to help you.

Comment: I should measure how many write operations per sec my program does when compared to the end result (when all blocks have been written).

Comment: So you only need it at the very end, and over all operation? Then just count the write ops and track the start and end time of your program's execution. Then calculate the runtime duration from that, and divide the number of ops by the timespan (in seconds).

Comment: Alright thanks. I think I know how to go from now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how you define

> number of read operations per second

you need to keep track of different values. You further specified that you only need the **write** operations per second over the entire execution time. Therefore, you only need to calculate the timespan in seconds your program ran, and divide the total write operations by that value:

```
double duration = (double) (endSystemNanos - startSystemNanos) / 1_000_000L;
double writeOpsPerSecond = (double) totalWriteOps / duration;
```

Comment: That's how I had it planned out after you've explained the procedure. That wouldn't work if I was writing in an infinite loop, right? Only for fixed number of write operations.

Comment: it would still work, assuming that you want to output the value at the very end, after for some reason your program terminates, for example, because the input ran out.